# mxnet binary operations only work in one direction

Tags: r, mxnet

I am trying to port some `mxnet` code from python. I am running into an issue with simple binary operations on symbols. I have a self-contained reproducible example below:

```
library(mxnet)
data <- mx.symbol.Variable('data')
x <- mx.symbol.FullyConnected(data = data, num.hidden = 10)

> x - 1 # this works
```

> C++ object <0x10229c700> of class 'MXSymbol' <0x10b248c10>

```
> 1 - x # this doesn't
```

> Error in 1 - x : non-numeric argument to binary operator

How can I subtract a symbol *from* a number using mxnet in R?

Comment: This will be fixed in https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/pull/6758

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in MXNet, which is now resolved in https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/pull/6758.